# работа с сессиями, посоветуйте технологию

Tags: php, сессия

Сессия хранится в базе данных. Когда выходит время жизни сессии, нужно выполнить PHP-скрипт. Как это сделать?

Comment: а зачем вам вызывать именно php скрипт? может просто обойтись job?

Comment: нужно оповестить всех слушателей, у какого пользователя закончилась сессия

Comment: брр php выполняется на стороне сервера. при запуске скрипта на php если сессия пользователя не будет найдена то он должен будет переброситься на страницу с авторизацией. А на стороне клиента можно на JS реализовать таймер который например по истечению какого то времени если пользователь не предпринимал действий будет пытаться перенаправить на страницу авторизации

Comment: дело не в авторизации. Пользователь должен видеть активность других пользователей

Comment: Ну так делайте select из бд о состоянии сессий каждые 30 секунд

Comment: это очень ресурсоемко. Я работаю с вебсокетами. Данная технология позволяет не опрашивать сервер. Если на сервере произойдут изменения, он сам отошлет во фронтенд данные. Для этого мне нужно событие завершения сессии, что-бы отправить во фронтенд данные о том, что пользователь вышел.

Comment: подождите, даже если вы это сделаете вам придется из бд на любой инсерт или апдейт посылать информацию. сделать селект один раз дешевле чем слать кучу раз апдейты и инсерты в сторону сервера (который в свою очередь будет перенаправлять уже клиенту). но дело ваше конечно, я бы не стал так делать

Comment: Данным методом я получаю изменение статусов в режиме реального времени и не нужно ждать 30 секунд.

Comment: Если работаете с сокетами, значит у вас крутится какой-то loop в нём можете раз в 30 секунд вытягивать сессии которые скоро закончатся и хранить их в массиве, который будете передавать в короткий loop, если уж для вас так важно моментальное срабатывание без лишних запросов к базе.

Comment: пожалуй, это наилучший вариант, который я нашел

Comment: Не обязательно. На стороне юзера emit события завершения сессии по таймеру.